# Why doesn't PayPal's IPN simulator work with https addresses?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

In PayPal's IPN simulator, if I enter a https:// URL, I get an error that says "We're sorry, we could not send an IPN." However, on an http:// URL it works fine. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because your SSL certificate is self-signed or otherwise deemed "invalid" by Paypal's IPN service.

Check your website's certificate in a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox by visiting the site over https and then clicking icon next to the `https` part of the url. If your site's certificate is bad, the `https` part of the URL will be grey or red instead of green and the clicking the icon will reveal more information about exactly why: for instance if your certificate is self-signed or expired.

Comment: The icon is green and it is verified by PositiveSSL. The PayPal IPN still doesn't work though...

Comment: Hm... what certificate authority is your certificate through? It is possible that the root CA is not trusted by PayPal....

Comment: @mellowfish87 is correct, the PP IPN simulator is not compatible with any SSL'd IPN script.  I don't think they support it right now for some weird reason, so testing has to be on Port 80.